# How to save a single .java file from eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm trying to save a single class file as a .java file from Eclipse. I've tried right clicking on the class, exporting as a JAR file and save to my desktop, but when I open it, it is just a bunch of weird symbols. How do I just export a single .java file??? Help please!

Comment: Can you please be a little clearer on what you are trying to achieve? Do you have a `.class` file which you want to convert back into a Java source file?

Comment: A `.class` file is compiled Java bytecode, it does not contain the Java source.

Answer (score 1):

Just drag and drop the file from Eclipse file browser to desktop.

OR

Just Copy the code complete code from the .java file and then create a new text file wherever you want using file explorer and paste the contents in it and save it. Then rename it to Filename.java

Here you should turn on show file extensions from setting else I don't think you will be able to change the extension.

Then you can compile the file by :

```
javac Filename.java
```

And run by:

```
java MainClass
```

And create JAR by:

```
jar cfve file.jar Main Main.class
```